# Javascript .test either returns nothing or false, when regex matches the tested string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript's inbuilt `.test()` function to test whether a string or regex matches. I took the regex from **[RegexLib](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=28)**, so I know that it matches the string it's tested against (in this case `joe@aol.com`), however it either returns false or nothing at all.

**Here's my code:**

```
var string = "joe@aol.com";
var pattern = [\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i;
var match = pattern.test(string);

document.write(match);
```

When the regex is encased in quotes, the test returns false, when it's not encased in anything, it returns nothing.

What I've tried so far:

- Simply using a single line, `var match = '[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i'.test("joe@aol.com");`.
- Using both `'` single quotes and `"` double quotes for both `regex` and `string`.
- Appending the regex with `/i` and `/g`.

I honestly don't know what's causing this issue, so any help would be great. It could be a complete rookie mistake, a forgotten syntax perhaps.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle I made up for you to play around with if you think you've got some idea of how to fix this up: http://jsfiddle.net/wFhEJ/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the opening slash for a regexp. The notation for a regexp is:

```
/regexp/flags
```

What happened with enclosing the regexp is that it became a string, and on jsFiddle `String.prototype.test` has been set by MooTools. MooTools seems to provide a `String.prototype.test` function, but it's not the same as `RegExp.prototype.test`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wFhEJ/2/

```
var string = "joe@aol.com";
var pattern = /[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i;
var match = pattern.test(string);

document.write(match);
```

Do note though that `document.write` is frowned upon. You might rather want `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match))` or something alike.

Comment: `document.write()` was just an easy way to print the value of `match` ;). Thanks for the edit, it's greatly appreciated.